# modifying queryset in django admin page for auth_users and a custom related model

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

So, I have a model `DailyTask` that has a OneToOneField to the `auth_users` model,
this is the `DailyTask` model fields :

> task_id
>
> task_date
>
> user ( OneToOneField )

Now each `user` has to submit a new `Task` report daily, already have an `AdminModel` that display all the submitted `Tasks` respectively to the logged in non `superuser`, here is the `AdminModel` :

```
class DailyTaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```

and I have created a `proxy Model` so I can create and register another `AdminModel` using the same Model :

```
class MyDailyTask(DailyTask):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

then the second AdminModel :

```
class DailyPresenceAdmin(DailyTaskAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter()

admin.site.register(MyDailyTask, DailyPresenceAdmin)
```

My only problem is, that in the `DailyPresenceAdmin` AdminModel, want to list all the `users` from `auth_users` that has not uploaded their `Task of the day` yet.

so it will be something like,

> if auth_users.user has no TaskID with the date equals to today's date in the DailyTask Model yet, then I want to take the user and list it in the DailyPresenceAdmin AdminModel.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a query from User model

```
User.objects.filter(mydailytask__task_date=timezone.today(), mydailytask__isnull=True)
```